# User Agent Class Library

Tags: javascript

I know that "useragent.js" and "user-agent-utils 1.8" is used to identify the type of the browser ,operating system,mobile devices etc,at the user end.

Can we identify the resolution/size of the screen(in pixels) using USER AGENT class library?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: User agent doesn't contain such data. You can just use Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Javascript not User Agent

```
window.screen.availHeight
```

Specifies the height of the screen, in pixels, minus interface features such as the taskbar in Windows.

```
window.screen.availWidth
```

Specifies the width of the screen, in pixels, minus interface features such as the taskbar in Windows.

```
window.screen.width
```

The total height of the screen, in pixels.

```
window.screen.height
```

The total width of the screen, in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get that data from the user agent. You can use Javascript:

```
var resolutionX = screen.width;
var resolutionY = screen.height;
```